# How to compare the records in SQL and remove the duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on a project Extracting data from excel to database (with help of MS BI tools)

It's just sample it would be help me lot if achieved though SQL queries

I have small questions which are Tools you will be recommend for me

Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services, SSAS Might be helpful for achieve in this task, since I will be working on major Data Analysis in future

or Just sql queries would sufficient!

```
 SELECT  [bl]
          ,[m]
          ,[sp]
          ,[ba]
          ,[p]
          ,[b]
          ,[Do]
          ,[Li]

      FROM [test].[dbo].[simpletable]
      group by [m],[s] ,[b]
          ,[p]
          ,[b]
          ,[D]
          ,[L]
```

error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'test.dbo.simpletable.block' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Comment: Do you need to aggrege `[Limit_min (3GPP/FAIL-Limit)]` column?

Comment: Yes that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query to remove all the duplicates
Do a partition over all the column that are repeating data.

```
       ;WITH rmvDuplicate
            AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [col1], [col2], [col3]
                                            ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) dup
                FROM    tableName)
        DELETE FROM rmvDuplicate
        WHERE   dup > 1
```